# How to Implement OWIN and Katana in MVC 5Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, katana, asp.net-mvc-5.1

i upgrade my application from mvc4 to mvc5. i am using Entity Framework code first approach in my application. i am confuse about OWIN and Katana. how i implement these concept in my web mvc5 application. please guide me.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC was not designed to work with OWIN. It's the ASP.NET Web API and SignalR that were built for OWIN and provide specific host. So you cannot implement those concepts in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 2):

So far the only MVC framweworks I have found that support OWIN are [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/) or [FubuMVC](http://fubuworld.com/fubumvc/introduction/#).